# Firebird SQL Select for Stacked Bar Graph

Tags: sql, report, firebird, birt

As an SQL newbie hobbyist I have a question relating to a Select for report generation. I am using Firebird RDBMS 2.1 and want to create a report in Eclipse Luna using BIRT.

I have a dataset of bolts with threads of many different diameters and length combinations. I have columns for fields like;

```
thread_diameter(d),
thread_length(l),
overall_length(o),
```

Numeric fields are not integer.

I am trying to create a graph to show a distribution chart of thread diameters as a percentage of total count, with each diameter grouping displaying sub-groups by length range as a percentage of the diameter group count.

I need to display the groups and sub-group counts as percentages as the counts will be thousands or millions.

Ultimately I think a stacked bar graph is the obvious choice.

I won't write code here as I will probably get it wrong and cause confusion, but an example of what I have to create would be;

```
Select diameter range r1 where d is greater than 5 less than 10,
How many r1 where length is between 0 and 20,
How many r1 where length is between 20 and 40,
etc,
etc.

Select diameter range r2 where d is greater than 10 less than 15,
Count r2 where length is between 0 and 20,
Count r2 where length is between 20 and 40,
etc.,
etc.
```

I gather I should be able to define the diameter and length ranges by an algorithm, and count the groupings to give me the data needed to create a stacked bar graph.

I have no idea of how to correctly right such an SQL query capable of efficiently counting items totalling in the thousands or millions.

Comment: You probably could use a Stored Procedure to do that. Try doing one without parameters as an example.

Comment: Show us your table definition, and some sample data.

Comment: I'll look into stored procedures, and see if I can create a sample dataset to share.